# date_default_timezone_set() function

Tags: php, ios, mysql

how are you i have an app in objective c is connected to a web site where appear some errors. that is the first, someone can help us please??

Strict Standards: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in /homepages/32/d661400388/htdocs/lib/ProjectDALC.php on line 581

Comment: what is the question ? can you show some code ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a PHP error telling you that the PHP configuration does not specify a timezone. Normally this would be set in your php.ini file with something like:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = "Australia/Adelaide"
```

Or, you can call date_default_timezone_set from individual pages like:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Adelaide");
// do other stuff...
?>
```

Note that this is entirely related to your PHP configuration and has nothing to do with iOS or MySQL